# Custom 403 page works one environment and not another

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, http-status-code-403

In my ASP.NET MVC web application, I am trying to send a custom error pages with 404 and 403 responses.  I'm able to do this on my local IIS with the following code in Global.asax.cs.  No web.config support required.

```
protected void Application_EndRequest()
{
    if (Context.Response.StatusCode == 404)
    {
        Response.Clear();

        var rd = new RouteData();
        rd.DataTokens["area"] = "";
        rd.Values["controller"] = "Error";
        rd.Values["action"] = "NotFound";

        IController c = new ErrorController();
        c.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), rd));
    }
    else if (Context.Response.StatusCode == 403)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        var rd = new RouteData();
        rd.DataTokens["area"] = "";
        rd.Values["controller"] = "Error";
        rd.Values["action"] = "Forbidden";

        IController c = new ErrorController();
        c.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), rd));
    }
}
```

However, this same code doesn't work when I deploy it to my test environment.  In my test environment, I still get the 403 response but I don't see my custom Forbidden view.  I just get the default 403 view from IIS.  What makes it even more odd is that the 404 view works in both environments.  I've spent all day comparing the web.config files and other IIS settings to try and pin down what is different about my test environment but no luck.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually forbidden (user permission, no read) on that path on the test server?

Is the test server running the same IIS as your dev machine?  Might be some server side config to change.

Comment: Yes, I cannot access the resource which is correct. The response has then status code 403 like it should but the markup rendered in the browser isn't my custom view like it is when i visit my licall IIS. My local IIS is v10 while the test environment is v7.